# Working remotely on the French work and holiday visa?

Tags: france, canadian-citizens, working-visas, working-holiday

Does anyone have any idea if it's possible to work remotely for a non-EU company on the French [work holiday visa](https://ca.ambafrance.org/Check-out-the-Work-Holiday-Visa-PVT)? I have the working holiday visa for Canadian citizens in France and I'd like to extend it.

If so, would I pay tax in France or the non-EU company?

Any other suggestions, links and hints are appreciated!

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean for "I have the Canadian work and holiday visa for France"? Canadian or French? "Holiday visa"? You should be more precise. What is your contract? As a free-lancer/"independent" (in this case is also your job to register and pay all relevant taxes in France), or as normal employee?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Working holiday visa is the name of the scheme (and a number of similar schemes), it sounds quite specific to me. I edited the wording slightly to make that even clearer.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback :) The edits are correct, thanks @Relaxed

Comment: Correct the visa is the "work & holiday visa" scheme.  My contract is a normal full time, permanent employee for the non-EU company.

Comment: @AnitaNg Technically, “full time” could be an issue too. There is no set limit to my knowledge but work is supposed to be incidental under this scheme. Didn't you submit a motivation letter to get your first visa?

Answer (score 3):

If you work and reside in France, by default you have to pay taxes in France. [The FAQ on the program](https://france-visas.gouv.fr/en_US/web/ca/dispositions-locales) includes a reminder of this. Many people wish there would be but the principle is simple and there is no blanket exception or special rules for remote work, non-EU employers or anything.

On the flip side, I don't see why remote work would be *forbidden* as you do have the right to work in France under this visa. Producing a work contract is also not mandatory to renew it (see FAQ) so you're clear on that front. Of course, your employer will not be equipped to withhold taxes for you or deal with the French tax office so you might find that meeting your tax obligations is more difficult than with a local contract.

In fact, I know that some fully remote companies prefer not to hire people in France at all to avoid running afoul of French tax and insurance laws (quite apart from their employees visa/residence status).

Comment: Thanks for your time in answering my question @Relaxed!  I thought full time was a good thing to show that I will have funds while i'm here.  My goal is still to enjoy living in France and experience being a local. :) 

Thanks for the FAQs too! I'm fine to pay the taxes in France; I just want to do the right thing and I can always go to an accountant in France - no problem.

Any idea how I can ensure I can pay the taxes properly? Thanks! :D

Answer (score 3):

just an update that I found an answer for myself. Note: not sure if it would work for you but hopefully this helps you at least go towards the right direction. :)

After going to Toulouse's Pole emploi, prefecture, l'inspection du travail, and CPAM offices, they all did not know really anything about the visa.  I talked to the Consulate of Canada in Jean Jures and she was helpful, friendly and patient. She told me that based on what she can see for the regulations and information about the work and holiday visa for Canadians in France, we CAN work remotely.

I also went to the Centre de finance publique toulouse to ask about taxes and they too were friendly, efficient and helpful.  I confirmed with them that for my situation, I just pay normal taxes - I do not need to register as a self-employed person or something like that.

Not sure if this info will change so I advise you ask for your specific situation as I will double check for myself again when it's time to file taxes for 2020 in 2021.  Good luck!